# Spring integration tests with two independent modules

Tags: java, spring, testing

how can I include all beans from two independent modules in integration test? I'm **not** using Spring Boot. So i have structure like this:

```
module A
module common
module B
```

then A has common dependency, also B has common dependency. I'm running my tests from B module, so I can actually scan packages from B and common. Is it possible to make my test see every bean in both, A and B modules?

EDIT: I have configured beans with annotations, so I use `@ComponentScan` for searching beans

Comment: Depending on how you configured "the discovery" and if `common` is included in `module A` / `module B` – wherever is needed. I don't know why would that be a problem since you normally use "beans" from external libraries – so treat `common` as one of those.

Comment: Assuming using maven, `A` could be dependency in `B` with **test** scope.

Comment: so I need to configure that at build tool level rather than java code right? Okay I think i get the point, thank you guys :]